# Constraint Eager Loading With Query Scopes

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationships

I am creating a admin panel and I have 3 tables in my DB: groups, roles, users. I have a many to many relationship between the users table and the roles table.
There is no laravel documentation explaining this functionality.

```
public function roles() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Role', 'user_roles');
}
```

And I have a one to many relationship between the groups table and the users table.

```
public function group() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Group');
}
```

Right now I want to apply filters to the query through eager loading. And with these I want to add the following dynamic filters.

```
public function scopeStatus($query, $status = null) {
    // If status is empty then return the query itself
    if (is_null($status)) {
        return $query;
    }

    return $query->where('status', $status);
}

public function scopeRole($query, $role = null) {
// If role is empty then return the query itself
if (is_null($role)) {
    return $query;
}

return $query->where('role', $role);
}

public function scopeGroup($query, $group = null) {
    // If group is empty then return the query itself
    if (is_null($group)) {
       return $query;
    }

    return $query->where('group_id', $group);
}
```

So that I can do some query like [the status and the group_id are just columns in the users table]

```
$users = User::with([
    'roles' => function ($query) use ($request) {
        $query->role($request['role']);
    }, 

    'group' => function($query) use ($request) {
        $query->group($request['group']);
    }
])
    ->status($request['status'])
    ->paginate(20);
```

But this is not working. I'm doing this through an AJAX request and I have tested the request parameters. This is what I get when I do `dd($request);`.

```
array:3 [▼
  "group" => "1"
  "role" => "1"
  "status" => "1"
]
```

Everything looks good but the I always receive and empty object. Please all your help will be appreciated.

Comment: Could you show sample `dd($request)` just before running `$users =User:: ...` ?

Comment: Okay, I will add it as an edit to the question

Comment: Start with `$users = User::status($request['status'])->paginate(20);`  - do you get results you expect?

Comment: Do you want to filter users with group=1, role=1 and status=1? Or do you want to load ALL users with status 1, but eager load only group 1 and role 1?

Comment: I want to do the filters group=1 role =1 and status = 1

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek `$users = User::status($request['status'])->paginate(20);` works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my question. I have realized that with eager loading you can't add a scope when constraining them. You must do all your conditional statements in the closure or a query builder.

So with my problem all the scopes but status are not needed. This is the new code:

```html
        $users = User::with([
            'roles' => function ($query) use ($request) {
                if (is_null($request['role'])) {
                    $query;
                } else {
                    $query->where('id', $request['role']);
                }
            },

            'group' => function ($query) use ($request) {
                if (is_null($request['group'])) {
                    $query;
                } else {
                    $query->where('id', $request['group']);
                }
            }
        ])->status($request['status'])
          ->paginate(20);
```